# Having a variable in the middle of an alias?

Tags: terminal, grep, command-line-interface, alias

I currently have a commonly used grep command:

```
    grep -r -w <SEARCH> --include \*.c --include \*.cpp --include \*.h
```

Want to have this as an alias (say, grepc) but be able to change the SEARCH in the middle. Is it possible to have this as a variable, and if so how would I do this / call it?

Comment: try `grep -r --include='*.'{c,h,cpp} -w` and then you can simply use `grepc 'whatever'`

Comment: @Sundeep I get the following :

        `grep: *.cpp: No such file or directory` 
        `grep: include: No such file or directory`

where include was my search term

Comment: @Sundeep fairly sure the --include needs to go after the search term, hence the above issue

Comment: which shell are you using? and what OS? `alias xyz="grep -r --include='*.'{c,h,cpp} -w"` and `xyz 'whatever'` works fine for me on bash/ubuntu

Comment: @Sundeep apologies, must have been a typo in my alias, a direct copy-paste of that has worked. Thanks bud (Y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to pass argument for this use case

```
alias xyz="grep -r --include='*.'{c,h,cpp} -w"
xyz 'whatever'
```

When arguments are needed to be passed, use functions instead. See [this Q&A on unix stackexchange for discussion between alias and functions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30925/in-bash-when-to-alias-when-to-script-and-when-to-write-a-function)